# $n$th order Polynomial for $(n+1)$ points

Tags: polynomials, regression, linear-regression

I was reading about Polynomial Fitting and found this sentence:

[image]

How can one reach this conclusion and prove it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation has proofs of this

Comment: @SteamyRoot Thanks... I had looked at "Polynomial Regression" but not "Polynomial Interpolation"... It had my answer...

Comment: @Arthur Thanks... I edited the title...